# Спарсить значение html в массив / объект

Tags: javascript, html, парсер, dom

На странице есть элемент `<span class="companies-rating__spec-name">`, я в цикле хочу получить текст внутри этих элементов. Написал следующий код:

```
var p = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    var p = document.getElementsByClassName('companies-rating__spec-name')[i].innerHTML;
}
```

но выдает `Undefined`. Подскажите как правильно подойти к решению, объект или массив использовать, как мне записать все значения, мне их просто вывести нужно чтобы скопировать.

Comment: Что выдает undefined?

Comment: консоль моего браузера google chrome

Comment: Я в шоке, откуда у Вас 2,1k баллов, с таким кодом? Может Ваш акк взломали?

Comment: даже не знаю оба ответа так хороши , какой выбрать посоветуйте пожалуйста?

Comment: @stack-it какой тебе понятней, проще, удобней, тот и выбирай )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var p = [];
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('companies-rating__spec-name');

for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
  p.push(elem[i].innerHTML);
  console.log(p[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var a = [];

[...document.getElementsByClassName('companies-rating__spec-name')].forEach(e => {
  a.push(e.innerHTML)
});

console.log(a);
```

```html
<span class="companies-rating__spec-name">1</span>
<span class="companies-rating__spec-name">2</span>
<span class="companies-rating__spec-name">3</span>
<span class="companies-rating__spec-name">4</span>
<span class="companies-rating__spec-name">5</span>
<span class="companies-rating__spec-name">6</span>
<span class="companies-rating__spec-name">7</span>
<span class="companies-rating__spec-name">8</span>
```